# wordpress header and container width will not stay at 100%

Tags: css, wordpress

my site at http://nemx.me/avant/ loads fine but when I size the with of the browser to about 600px and scroll to the right the header and container background no longer stretch.

i've trying adding in `width 100%` and using google developer tools to try and locate what css tag is causing this but after 4hrs i'm still stuck, any suggestions? i don't see a `max-width` that would cause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `white-space: nowrap;` set on `.main_weltxt`. This is causing the issue.

```
.main_weltxt {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif!important;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6f9186;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from the above CSS

Comment: I commented it out, but there is still white space to the right. the site header, middle, and footer should stretch to the right/fill to the right. like it does when it expands

Comment: I just checked the link for another look and it's working fine now

Comment: hmm that did work, thats it was probably cached. i checked on my phone and its flowing correctly

Comment: I'm going to 300px (min allowed). Using chrome MAC OSX. The problem was present originally but now it's ok. Try and check it from another browser on your end, could be a caching issue

Comment: thanks. do you have a website, i see that you're a web developer. do you do freelance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36179/discussion-between-acctman-and-vector)

Comment: hi Acctman, Could you mark this as correct to help other users with the same probably, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a max-width rule that's preventing the background from stretching:

[image]

Disabling that rule extends the background to the full browser width in both sections.

Comment: i disabled it but its still there... reduce your browser width to about 400px or so then scroll to the right. the background should still fill out but instead it appears to be striking

Comment: Not seeing what you're seeing - please paste a screen cap.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using `display: inline-block` on your `.nav-menu li` elements.
Therefor your navigation is 'overflowing' your website and causing this.

Try using:

```
.nav-menu li {
  float: left;
  positon: relative;
}
```

Also, remove `white-space: no-wrap` from `.main_weltxt`

Comment: no luck, header, footer and middle sections are still not expanding to the right when sided down

Comment: So you want your website to remain the exact same width, and not scale down with the browser?